# Alignment Issue with Table Structure

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is the code for aligning contact details:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table width="900" class="contact-details">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="./images/Mobile.png"></td>
        <td>
          <p>832.674.6834</p>
        </td>
        <td><img src="./images/fax.png"></td>
        <td>
          <p>271.217.4981</p>
        </td>
        <td><img src="./images/email.png"></td>
        <td>
          <p>test@testpineced.com</p>
        </td>
        <td><img src="./images/address.png"></td>
        <td>
          <p>1055 Loremips Tr. Kity, TX</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <style>
      img {
        /* width: 100%; */
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see there is gap difference in between images and text content. Can you please help me to make equal gap difference and fit full content inside the table class.

Please see the screenshot attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKZt7.jpg

Comment: Please, use flexbox for this, not a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **css** class for `td` and for each td can specify the inline `width` & `height`

```css
.img {
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<table width="900" class="contact-details">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url(./images/Mobile.png); width: 50px; height: 80px;"> </td>
        <td><p>832.674.6834</p></td>
        <td class="img" style="background-image:url(./images/fax.png); width: 50px; height: 80px;"> </td>
        <td><p>271.217.4981</p></td>
        <td class="img" style="background-image:url(./images/email.png); width: 50px; height: 80px;"> </td>
        <td><p>test@testpineced.com</p></td>
        <td class="img" style="background-image:url(./images/address.png); width: 50px; height: 80px;"> </td>
        <td><p>1055 Loremips Tr. Kity, TX</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of background size: cover, i tried background-position and it worked. Thanks for your time Shiv Kumar @shiv-kumar-baghel

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="900" class="contact-details" >
    <tr>
        <td style='width: 30px'><img style='width: 30px' src="./images/Mobile.png"></td>
        <td>832.674.6834</td>
        <td style='width: 30px'><img style='width: 30px' src="./images/fax.png"></td>
        <td>271.217.4981</td>
        <td style='width: 30px'><img style='width: 30px' src="./images/email.png"></td>
        <td>test@testpineced.com</td>
        <td style='width: 30px'><img  style='width: 30px' src="./images/address.png"></td>
        <td>1055 Loremips Tr. Kity, TX</td>
    </tr>
```

just change the width px according to the image width

Comment: I tried, but still getting this. Please see: https://imgur.com/a/uu7anr5 . Also I need to fit the last text align equal to end of green box.

Comment: Actually you dont need to have the image in its own <TD>..  just have it within the same TD as the value..
 <td style='width: 25%'><img src="./images/Mobile.png"> 832.674.6834</td>

Answer (score 0):

```
 **You have to remove width="900" and add padding to <td> element**

 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
  img {
    /* width: 100%; */
    display: block;
  }
  table{
        margin:0 auto;
  }
  td{
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-left: 1%;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table  class="contact-details">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="./images/Mobile.png"></td>
    <td>
      <p>832.674.6834</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src="./images/fax.png"></td>
    <td>
      <p>271.217.4981</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src="./images/email.png"></td>
    <td>
      <p>test@testpineced.com</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src="./images/address.png"></td>
    <td>
      <p>1055 Loremips Tr. Kity, TX</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>


 </body>
 </html>
```